# Not able to save JSON values to Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, json

i have one php file in server which select some values from db and create a JSON then from my html file am accessing that JSON .
this is my json

```
 [{"id":"1","Intensity":"1","Location":"12.48,77.26"},
  {"id":"2","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.47,77.26"},
  {"id":"3","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.47,77.27"},
  {"id":"4","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.46,77.24"},
  {"id":"5","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.44,77.24"},
  {"id":"6","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.44,77.28"},
  {"id":"7","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.50,77.28"},
  {"id":"8","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.45,77.30"},
  {"id":"9","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.41,77.21"}]
```

and am using following code to store "Location value to an array inside javascript but its not storing.When i print that array using alert the alert is not showing .

the result of data in following code is my JSON itself.

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   alert(data[i]['id']);
   var loc = data[i]['Location'].split(',');
   alert(loc); //not printing
}
```

when i print `alert(data.length)` value is 469.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `data` is a json string, you need to parse it into json object.

do this

```
obj = JSON.parse(data);

for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    alert(obj[i]['id']);
    var loc = obj[i]['Location'].split(',');
    alert(loc); //not printing
}
```

Comment: +1, but a nitpick: JavaScript does not have JSON objects. It has JS objects, and strings with JSON values. :)

Comment: ZZlalani i need one more help

Comment: Thanks @Amadan . check it now  ;)

Comment: zzlalani: i want to display circles in google map according to that location cordinates.if am hard coding that location values then i can see circles but when i add location values from json array its not showing do u want my full code???

Comment: circle are working in this hard coded html file http://zonewebs.org/website/naveen/source/map.html

Comment: but its not working when i take the json location values from above code   check this link   http://zonewebs.org/website/naveen/source/newmap.html

Comment: you have typo in the code change `var longt=lac[1];` to `var longt=loc[1];`

Comment: ZZlalani :thansk allot

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse your data.

```
data = JSON.parse(data)
```